# Listener isn't working on my ASP.NET button from my Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Basically my Jquery isn't firing on my `onclick` of the button in my ASP.NET , I am new to using Jquery so I'm not sure if my syntax is correct. I am obviously calling it from the `<body>` via the `onload`. My code is below so I'm just seeking help tryign to find why it won't load , so my actually question is: Why won't my Jquery function load from my button?

```
<head runat="server">
   <title>Fire Test</title>
   <link id="stylesheet" href="ControlStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" runat="server" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Production/jquery.js"></script>
   <style type="text/css">
      .style1
      {
          font-size: x-large;
      }
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function init() {
       $("#OkBtn").on("click", alertFire);
           function alertFire() {
              alert("Update Successful!");
           }
       }

   </script>
</head>
<body background="../icons/Building-Confidence-logo.jpg" onload="init();">
```

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET, using some dev tools (chrome/IE/Firebug) make sure that the ID of the control you're trying to select is actually what it is being named by your application. Many times in ASP.NET, the application itself will add "ctl00_" to the beginning of control id's on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$("#<%=OkBtn.ClientID%>").on("click", alertFire);
```

Also you do not need to create the function separately

you can go:

```
$("#<%=OkBtn.ClientID%>").on("click", function(){
        alert("Update Successful!");
    });
```

**update**

Instead of using init on the body load why not use jquery load event

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#<%=OkBtn.ClientID%>").on("click", function(){
            alert("Update Successful!");
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

One thing that it might be is if jQuery is not loading properly. Are you getting javascript errors saying that `$ is undefined`.

Try getting rid of all script blocks an put this in

```
<script>
    $(function(){ 
        alert("Hello"); 
    });
</script>
```

if this does not pop up "Hello" on each page refresh then the issue is with this line and the loading of jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Production/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: I will give this a go now my friend & get back to you right away :)

Comment: This sadly had no effect what so ever.

Comment: why minus with no explanation?

Comment: As I commented on the other answer, your second suggestion doesn't **fix** anything, although it's a good *suggestion*. And you first suggestion has nothing to do with anything

Comment: what is the ID of your asp:Button ?

Comment: @Ian it does. we have changed just a normal id selector `$("#OkBtn")` to selecting an id from asp.net button `$("#<%=OkBtn.ClientID%>")`... how does this have nothing to do with anything?

Comment: @Adween I honestly must be going crazy. I must be mixing stuff up, I thought the OP was using `ClientID`. My comment about your first suggestion was in regards to **"Also you do not need to create the function separately"**. My comment about your second suggestion was in regards to the OP being edited to have the `<body onload="init()">` (which your suggestion effectively does the same thing as). Sorry about that!

Comment: IT didnt achieve my end goal , of even making the alert appear and my ID for my ASP.NET button is OkBtn

Comment: @Kallumasaurus does you asp:button look like this `<asp:Button runat="server ID="OkBtn" />`

Comment: @Adween yes it does mate :)

Comment: @Kallumasaurus well then i'm confused. Try using a class instead so `<asp:Button runat="server ID="OkBtn" CssClass="TEST" />` and then `<script>$(function(){ $('.TEST').click(function(){ alert("ARRRGGGH"); }); });</script>`

Comment: I really don't want to be using a CSS class to call the alert sorry.

Comment: @Kallumasaurus it was just to test. i have changed my post with another test. i do not think that jquery is being loaded correctly can you give my suggestion a try

Comment: I will give it a shot now.

Comment: Nothing mate , none of the suggestions even popped the Alert up , its worrying me this... ahah :')

Comment: @Kallumasaurus jquery is not loading then. what does you url look like.

Comment: try this `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Sadly this didn't work, just noticed the script comment... will try this also , thanks for not giving up!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49958/discussion-between-adween-and-kallumasaurus)

Comment: YOU HERO! this worked , it was the way in which i was addressing my code. I took out the "~/production/" and now it all works fine , WELL DONE SIR!

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your onclick in the `$(function() { });`

So:

```
$(function(){
   $("#<%= OkBtn.ClientID %>").on("click", alertFire);
});
```

Edit:

In line with your edit, remove the Init from your `body` load.

Comment: While this is a suggestion (that I agree with), it doesn't **fix** the problem. The OP is calling `init` onload, which is basically the same as what you have. You should also explain **why** the OP should change their code to this

Comment: @Ian - No, ASP.NET load methods are NOT the same as the JQuery ones

Comment: I am new to this so I really am just lost into all of this world of Jquery.

Comment: @webnoob There is no "ASP.NET load method" here, it's a simple body `load` event

Comment: @Ian - Check his OP, it didn't contain the `Body` tag so this answer was correct at the time of posting it.

Comment: @Ian - It might be there now, it wasn't when I answered.

Comment: @webnoob Sorry, I deleted my comment. You're absolutely right, **Dumisani added** it in...that's wrong. I based my comments completely on that `<body>` tag being there, woah

Comment: @Ian - No problem, I assumed something odd was going on. This also uses the selector that will allow it to work with ASP.NET controls.

Comment: the <body background="../icons/Building-Confidence-logo.jpg" onload="init();"> was in my actual original post ...

Comment: @Kallumasaurus - I'm sorry but it wasn't. The OP is at the bottom of the edit screen and it's not there. Regardless, this should sort your issue now if you follow the advice.

Comment: @webnoob Absolutely, the selector change is definitely helpful. ASP.NET doesn't always change the ID, but when it does, you need to use the `ClientID`, and it's safer to always include anyways

Comment: I will try this way of yours one more time , hopefully it will work and i shall mark answer.

Comment: Alas , it did not work none of these suggestions are even opening the Alert it is just running to my insert ( but that's off topic ) and completing my task ...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#OkBtn").click(function() {
      alert("Update Successful!");
   });
});
```

Do not put it inside your `init` function